# ¿ Como sumar los elementos de Array?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola estoy tratando de crear un programa que me sume los números múltiplos de 3 y 5 que se encuentren entre el 0 y el 10.
Bien, no se que hago mal que la suma me da 33, cuando debería de ser 23.
¿ Ven el error de mi código ...?
Gracias.

```js
function multiple(valor, multiple) {
    resto = valor % multiple;
    if (resto == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// Arrays que contendran los valores multiples del 3 y del 5
let multiples_3 = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (multiple(i, 3))
        multiples_3.push(i);

    if (multiple(i, 5))
        multiples_3.push(i);
}

let a = multiples_3
let suma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < multiples_3.length; i++) {
    suma += multiples_3[i]
}
alert(suma)
```

Comment: 3+5+6+9+10 = 33

Comment: estas confundido @Miguel Espeso, los múltiplos de 3 son 3,6,9 y de 5 son 5 y 10 y si los sumas das 33

Comment: Hola, tienen razon, es 33. De lo que no me di cuenta es de que el enunciado decía: números por debajo de 10.                                                      Gracias por el apoyo, la lógica la expreso bien @Carlos Muñoz en su respuesta.. Gracias a todos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el límite 10 es abierto (es decir no debe considerar al 10) el problema está al usar el operador `<=` en lugar de `<` en el for

```
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
```

El código corregido (con ciertas redundancias eliminadas) sería

```js
function multiple(valor, multiple) {
    return valor % multiple === 0;
}

// Arrays que contendran los valores multiples del 3 y del 5
let multiples_3 = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (multiple(i, 3))
        multiples_3.push(i);

    if (multiple(i, 5))
        multiples_3.push(i);
}

let suma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < multiples_3.length; i++) {
    suma += multiples_3[i]
}

alert(suma);
```

Comment: considero que se debería dar respuesta hasta que el OP deje en claro que necesita por que su redacción es confusa y se puede interpretar que si necesita considerar el 10 también

Comment: Gracias, @Carlos Muñoz acertó con su lógica, si bien yo no redacte bien la pregunta. Iba  a editar la pregunta, pero dice : **múltiplos de 3 y 5 entre el 0 y el 10 ** por lo que Carlos Muñoz acertó, y la pregunta esta bien echa.